# Basic authentication with IIS 7 reverse proxy

Tags: security, iis-7, reverse-proxy, http-basic-authentication

In our DMZ we currently have a facade or proxy web page (asp.net webform), which forwards requests to a web service (asp.net web service) in our intranet, then relays the web services response back to the caller.  Client software posts data to the web page with a user name & password in the url.  The web page creates basic authentication credentials based on the user name & password url parameters and calls the interal web service, then relays the web service response back to the caller via the web pages response content.

I'm looking at the viabilty of using the reverse proxy functionality of IIS 7 instead of using the proxy web page.  The web service in our intranet will still require basic authentication, so is it possible to utilize the username/password url parameters to create a basic authentication crediential with IIS 7's reverse proxy functionality?